# ionic pass storage value to subscribe method

Tags: ionic3

My session values are stores in  array

```
this.storage.get('userinfo').then((data)=>{
    let sid = data.sid;
  });
```

I want to pass this `sid` to my php call. I used the below code. But it is not working. How to pass this in subscribe method.

```
   this.http.get(Constant.domainConfig.base_url+'api/restaurant_api/restaurants?roid='+sid).subscribe(data=>{
  this.list = data.json();
  console.log(data.json());
})
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.storage.get('userinfo').then((data)=>{
    let sid = data.sid;
   this.http.get(Constant.domainConfig.base_url+'api/restaurant_api/restaurants?roid='+sid).subscribe(data=>{
  this.list = data.json();
  console.log(data.json());
})

  });
```